# SQL TOP 20 results per user, using their highest value in column 1. If multiple of the same value, select based on highest column 2 value

Tags: sql, azure

I've played around with this a lot over the past few days and seem to be going around in circles, so thought I would ask for help before I end up bald.

I have managed to receive the Top 20 entries based on the maximum value in column 1, but does not take into account duplicates in Stat1 where Stat2 is higher etc. So if a user has two entries with the same Stat1, it returns both.

The data would be like:

| UID | Stat1 | Stat2 | Stat3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 26 | 18 | 4 |
| 1 | 20 | 26 | 8 |
| 2 | 26 | 19 | 9 |
| 3 | 30 | 5 | 1 |
| 4 | 26 | 18 | 6 |
| 3 | 12 | 8 | 2 |

Expected Results:

| UID | Stat1 | Stat2 | Stat3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 30 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 26 | 19 | 9 |
| 4 | 26 | 18 | 6 |
| 1 | 26 | 18 | 4 |

This is my latest query that returns as mentioned above with the duplicates and not taking the Stat2 column into account.

```
SELECT
    TOP 20
    t1.UID,
    isnull(t1.Stat1, 0) AS Stat1,
    isnull(t1.Stat2, 0) AS Stat2,
    isnull(t1.Stat3, 0) AS Stat3
FROM
    TABLE t1
WHERE
    t1.Stat1 = (
        SELECT
            MAX(t2.Stat1)
        FROM
            TABLE t2
        WHERE
            t2.UID = t1.UID
    )
ORDER BY
    Stat1 DESC,
    Stat2 DESC,
    Stat3 DESC
```

I also tried returning all values. Looping through in PHP to manually remove duplicates.(Which works) I just don't like that method as I feel it's wasteful.

Comment: `UID` normally means unique identifier - however in your case this appears to not be the case; do you have a primary key?

Comment: Do you want the top 20 rows overall, or per user? Your description says per user, your query shows overall.

Comment: @Stu I don't have a primary key set

Comment: Looking for per user, Group by UID obviously needs aggregate, but not sure how to check for the highest in Stat2 as max(Stat1) returns the first highest if duplicates. I believe I need to alter some more conditions in the where, but idk

Comment: "sql" is a standard, not a database. Syntax changes between databases e.g. Some RDBMSs provide an ISNULL() function that can be used when dealing with potentially null values. MySQL, MariaDB, and Oracle Database each have an ISNULL() function that returns 1 if its argument is null , and 0 if it's not. SQL Server also has an ISNULL() function, but it works differently. **Choose a database in the tags please.**

Comment: Your example data are insufficient to demonstrate the top-20 mechanism. As for the maximum: do you want to show the first result per user in decreasing order of stat1, and then stat2, and then stat3? The duplicate logic needs more explaining with examples.

Comment: Do you want to calculate the maximum and number of occurrences at the maximum value separately for each of the statistics, choose the first statistic for which there is only one value at the maximum, and then only show rows having that maximum? If so, there will only be one row per user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `row_number()` to determine the "rows per uid"  and `select distinct` to remove duplicates from the result. e.g:

```
select distinct
    UID, Stat1, Stat2, Stat3    
from (
  select
      *
      , row_number() over(partition by uid order by stat1 DESC, stat2 DESC) as rn
  from mytable
  ) as d
where rn < 4 --<< increase this number to suit how many "per uid"
order by
     UID, Stat1 DESC, Stat2 DESC, Stat3
```

| UID | Stat1 | Stat2 | Stat3 | notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1126 | 18 | 4 |  |
| 1 | 1120 | 26 | 8 |  |
| 1 | 126 | 18 | 4 |  |
| 2 | 1126 | 19 | 9 |  |
| 2 | 126 | 19 | 9 |  |
| 2 | 26 | 19 | 9 |  |
| 3 | 1130 | 5 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 1112 | 8 | 2 |  |
| 3 | 130 | 5 | 1 |  |
| 4 | 26 | 18 | 6 | << there are 3 duplicate rows of this data in the table |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-Bd9yJXr)

Comment: Thanks! I think I get the desired result by setting rn = 1 and removing the UID from the final ORDER. Will set it up and test

Comment: you can also try things at the fiddle site e.g. without uid in the order: https://dbfiddle.uk/7dYito97